# C# data types to SQL Server data types

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How can I "convert" C# datatype to SQL Server datatype (the `SqlDbType` is known)

i.e:

```
C# -> "String"
SQL Server -> N'String'
```

Comment: share the code where you need this.

Comment: Except you have some specific code generation application based on a SQL Server database, this is usually not needed : ADO.NET do it automatically when adding parameters to a query. Please share the code so we can check this.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? are you looking to generate your DB from classes? If so, look at Entity Framework, Code-First. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318010/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Let-s-Try-It and look at **FluentAPI**. This is a very powerful way to create a DB from your classes.

Comment: Does you found problem insert different language data in database ?

Comment: Why you don't use parameters. Then you don't have to think about this issue

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this. It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 10):

Try This:
Its a Extension class, so on the file you want to use these methods on add:

```
using Utility;
```

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace Utility
{
    public static class TypeExtension
    {
        public static SqlDbType ToSqlDbType(this Type clrType)
        {
            var s = new SqlMetaData("", SqlDbType.NVarChar, clrType);
            return s.SqlDbType;
        }


        public static Type ToClrType(SqlDbType sqlType)
        {
            switch (sqlType)
            {
                case SqlDbType.BigInt:
                    return typeof (long?);

                case SqlDbType.Binary:
                case SqlDbType.Image:
                case SqlDbType.Timestamp:
                case SqlDbType.VarBinary:
                    return typeof (byte[]);

                case SqlDbType.Bit:
                    return typeof (bool?);

                case SqlDbType.Char:
                case SqlDbType.NChar:
                case SqlDbType.NText:
                case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
                case SqlDbType.Text:
                case SqlDbType.VarChar:
                case SqlDbType.Xml:
                    return typeof (string);

                case SqlDbType.DateTime:
                case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
                case SqlDbType.Date:
                case SqlDbType.Time:
                case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
                    return typeof (DateTime?);

                case SqlDbType.Decimal:
                case SqlDbType.Money:
                case SqlDbType.SmallMoney:
                    return typeof (decimal?);

                case SqlDbType.Float:
                    return typeof (double?);

                case SqlDbType.Int:
                    return typeof (int?);

                case SqlDbType.Real:
                    return typeof (float?);

                case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
                    return typeof (Guid?);

                case SqlDbType.SmallInt:
                    return typeof (short?);

                case SqlDbType.TinyInt:
                    return typeof (byte?);

                case SqlDbType.Variant:
                case SqlDbType.Udt:
                    return typeof (object);

                case SqlDbType.Structured:
                    return typeof (DataTable);

                case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
                    return typeof (DateTimeOffset?);

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sqlType");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server, the method ToSqlDbType throws: The dbType NVarChar is invalid for this constructor (SqlMetaData).

Answer (score 3):

First, you can get the mapping list from MSDN. They can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

Then, simply create a hash table (HashTable) to look up one type and convert it to the relevant SqlDbType. Something like this:

```
private static types = new HashTable<Type, SqlDbType>();
public static SqlDbType GetSqlDbType(Type type)
{
    if (types == null)
    {
        var types = new HashTable<Type, SqlDbType>();
        types.Add(int.GetType(), SqlDbType.Int);
        // And so forth...
    }

    return types[type];

}
```

Or words to that effect. Naturally, refactor for StyleCop compliance and maintainability. (I wrote this off the top of my head without an IDE and after only one cup of coffee.)

**EDIT**

Note that this can get fuzzy when dealing with resolution of .NET strings. Is it a varchar, an nvarchar, a text, or a memo? In those cases, this method won't have any way of knowing, and you will likely have to make a more informed decision after invoking the method based on the table and column name (or procedure and parameter name).

Comment: Mike nice answer but he probably wants to know how to use a value in a query. So NVarChar uses `N'yourvalue'` an Integer is just `1` a boolean must be converted to a Bit and so forth

Comment: What you are assuming he's asking and what he is asking are two very different things. He explicitly asked for a conversion between a CLR type and a SqlDbType. That's what I gave him.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do conversions like that but probably there is a better way:

I assume you want to insert a value using C# into a SQL query.

Why you don't use parameters?

Instead of:

```
SqlCommand command = 
    new SqlCommand(String.Format(
       "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mycolumn = {0}", 
       ConvertValueToSql(whateverobject))); 
// ConvertValueToSql is what you are asking basically
```

Try to do this:

```
// Conversion list of used types
Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> typeConversion = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();
typeConversion.Add(typeof(String), SqlDbType.NVarChar);
typeConversion.Add(typeof(Int32), SqlDbType.Integer);
// you can even do this if you want
typeConversion.Add(typeof(MyCustomImageClass), SqlDbType.VarBinary);
typeConversion.Add(typeof(MyOtherNiceClass), SqlDbType.NVarChar);

// In the method
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mycolumn = @Value");
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Value", typeConversion[whateverobject.GetType()]) { Value = whateverobject } );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old, but still valid, question, so here's a different way.  Someone already did this coding.  If you execute a query similar to this...

```
select

    @@serverName  as [Varchar],
    GetDate()     as [DateTime],
    3.14159       as [Decimal],
    256           as [Int],
    :
    :
    -- And So On
```

...your database driver will do the data type mapping for you.  You just have to retrieve the data and access the resulting column definitions.  The column name will be the DBMS data type (name) and the column data type will be the data type for whatever language in which you are working.  Your query can be limited to the specific DBMS data types you care about.  Note that this is not limited to any particular database management system.  One caveat is that this doesn't tell you which data types require length parameters.