# c# type to sql type string

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create an sql table from a T, however I am having problems with getting the right c# type to the right sql type.

Here is my method,

```
public static void CreateSqlTableFromT<T>(string connectionString)  where T : new()
        {
            IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.Append("CREATE TABLE ");
            query.Append(typeof(T).Name);
            query.Append(" ( ");

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                query.Append(properties[i]);
                query.Append(" ");
                query.Append(properties[i].GetType());
                query.Append(", ");
            }

            if (properties.Count > 1) { query.Length -= 2; }
            query.Append(")");
            using (var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand createTableCommand = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), con);
                createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

In this line, I want to convert the C# variable type to an equivalent SQL type

```
query.Append(properties[i].GetType());
```

Is there a way in c# to get the matching sql type from a c# type without having to do a lot of if statements?

For example, a c# decimal should be converted to money.

Comment: you can make your own mapping and then make some method whic accepts one type and returns equivalent in sql

Comment: @wudzik thats what i am thinking but it means that i have to check for every type, was wondering if there was somthing built in for this that could help

Comment: C# doesn't have a special feature for this. We use to have a mapping table, wudzik mentioned that. In fact, it's not possible to be very accurate sometimes because it depends on your requirements. In our case we had Decimal c# types mapped to different precisions in the database.

Comment: You could create a dictionary for all the c# types and use it as mentioned in the SO link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997526/c-sharp-data-types-to-sql-server-data-types

Comment: You could use an ORM, such as NHibernate, that would do it all for you.

Comment: Check this table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Comment: thak you all that really helped

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is simply no.